# get content from a website by using a css-path

Tags: php, css, parsing, path, file-get-contents

is it possible to get content from a website by using the css path?

for example

```
     html 
     body#tplThread 
     div#mainContainer 
     div#main div#possd443.message 
     div.messageInner 
     div.messageContent 
     div.messageContentInner 
     h3#postTops443.messageTitle span
```

Comment: CSS means Cascading **Style** Sheet, so cannot **get** content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

Domdocument is the way to go:

```
function makeDom( $html_code ) {
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->LoadHTML($html_code, LIBXML_NONET);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($this->dom);
return $xpath
}
```

than use:

```
$xpath->query('//div[@id="desiredid"]/a[@href="desiredhref"]')
```

here is a great tutorial on Xpath syntax:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

If the item you want to select has an id you do not even need a full path, selecting with nodename and id is enough as id is unique accross the whole page.